# php file_exists of a path makes no sense

Tags: php, drupal, caching, file

in my drupal module code i check if a path exists but the condition is not true even the path is there

```
// for debugging
$con .= $path;
$con .= "<br>";
$con .= strval( file_exists($path) );
$con .= "<br>";
$con .= strval( is_dir($path) );
$con .= "<br>";
// end debug

if (file_exists( $path )) {
    // do bla
}
```

i read http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php
and tried to clearstatcache() before but no change.

Also tried with a standalone php snippet which works fine!

```
<?php
$path = '/mnt/dataC/ebook';
$con = '';
$con .= strval( file_exists($path) );
$con .= strval( is_dir($path) );
echo $con;
?>
```

output: 11

the path is an external usb drive.

```
/dev/sdf1 on /mnt/dataC type reiserfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

reinstalling modules and clearing drupal cache doesnt help either

Comment: Does `$path` match in both scripts?

Comment: Are you using the same example path in your real code?

Comment: @Pekka - other way round, it gives false negative.

Comment: yeah, I re-read and understand now. Are the paths identical? Are you running this as the same user?

Comment: yes. but it's fine, it doesnt appear anymore. thx for the support !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - permissions did not suffice on a parent dir, not sure how it came, i set them to 775 on all dirs, maybe on remount